# Codeigniter File Uploading

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a section on my site where users can upload a file, and it stores it in the database to be viewed later.

I want to know how I can make it so users can add another file and it updates it kinda like this:

VERSION FILENAME

1.1     Test2.zip

1.0     Test.zip

If this is a little vague let me know, I'll revise it, also another note... I'm a beginner.

EDIT: Here is a more detailed explanation.

I have an area where you can upload a mod. I need to make it so that when a user uploads their mod they input the name of the file, the version, and then upload it. Then on the mod page it displays what they input + the file/download link. Then if they wish they can upload another file, where it will also get added to the list of files they have uploaded. Now instead of 1 file, it shows 2 files, their name/version, and their download links.

Comment: Are you saving file as binary data or just a link in the db ?

Comment: Just as a link so it doesn't bog down the database.

Comment: Just see what the last version number of that file was and increment it. There's a whole bunch of file functions in PHP you could use: http://www.php.net/manual/de/ref.filesystem.php
You could take a look at glob().
If you save the version number in the database, it's even easier. Just fetch it, increment it and use it as the version for the new upload. We don't know what you want to archive exactly , what kind of versioning you want etc. If you tell us more, we're able to help further.

Comment: I edited the OP now with a more detailed explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are allowing the user to enter the revision and filename, you need a separate table that keeps track of that. The table should be a log type table and each user will have multiple entries of files uploaded. Maybe something like below.

```
user_id | filename | revision | date
-----------------------------------------
  1     |Test2.zip | 1.1      | 2012-03-05
  1     |Test.zip  | 1.0      | 2012-03-04
```

Just an idea, perhaps you can control the revision number/filename and come up with a scheme to manage filenames and revisions. That way you won't have to create a separate table and can manage through a filesystem scheme.

Comment: So you're saying I should create a seperate table with user_id, filename, revision, date, mod_id? And join the mod table and the mod_files table together

Comment: Yes, assuming you have the user enter the revision and filename. This is because after a new file is uploaded, you won't be able to track where the old file is. (Especially if there is no scheme to define which revision ties to which file.) If you create a new table, then you can reference old revisions and old files simply by doing a join.